# Counting all rows by all columns returning column name and row counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, unpivot

I would like to summary a table with a lot of columns, any suggestions

```
Select column(names), Count(*)
from table
Group by column(names)
```

resulting in

```
**Cloumn** **Count**
Column 1    24
Column 2    75
column 3    35
```

.           .
.           .
.           .

Comment: I'm using mssql server 2016

Answer (score 1):

I would use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT tt.colname, COUNT(*)
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES ('Column1'), ('Column2'), ('Column3'), . . 
     ) tt (colname)
GROUP BY tt.colname;
```

If you want count only non-null values then include also column value :

```
SELECT tt.colname, COUNT(tt.colval)
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
         ( VALUES ('Column1', Column1), 
                  ('Column2', Column2), 
                  ('Column3', Column3), 
                  . . .
         ) tt (colname, colval)
GROUP BY tt.colname;
```

Comment: Works, but returning same count on all columns includng NULL

Comment: @MANY. . . Second approach should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that most people refer Microsoft SQL Server just as SQL (incorrect but common) Unpivot them

```
SELECT ColumnName, Count(Value)
FROM (
    SELECT ColumnName, Value
    FROM yourTable
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES('Column1', Column1),('Column2', Column2),('Column3', Column3)
    ) A(ColumnName, Value)
) T
GROUP BY ColumnName
```